# How can I get the QObject::deleteLater() to zero the object?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, qobject

Normally when I delete an object I set it to zero. This helps in that I code my routines to check the object is not zero then proceed.

However if I use the `deleteLater()` function I have lost control of it.  I don't know if its a valid item or if I need to create a new one.  The solution I found was just to keep track of the state separately however is there a better way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is nothing wrong if you call `deleteLater()` on your object and then set your pointer to `nullptr`. Qt framework will safely delete the object for you.

As an alternative you can also connect to destroyed signal to be notified of your object's destruction and set your pointer to `nullptr` in that slot.

Answer (score 10):

You can use QPointer if the object that is being deleted is a QObject. This will set it to NULL.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean, "zero the pointer"? In C++ it's more important than in Java to make the distinction between the object and a pointer to it. Here, it's especially important, because if you zero the object its destructor won't work. If you zero a pointer to the object, no problem, because Qt will have added another pointer to the "objects-to-be-deleted" list.